# Is there a way to force all cPanel users to change their passwords one time?

Tags: security, email, exim

One of the cPanel servers I am running has constant troubles with compromised email accounts. I believe many of the users on this server have very weak passwords. I have increased the minimum password security, but that only takes effect when passwords are changed... Is there any way to force a one-time password change for all cPanel accounts and cPanel email addresses? This way I could force all users to generate new, secure passwords.

---

**UPDATE:** I have found that each account has files at `~/etc/domain.name/{passwd,shadow}` which contain Unix-style passwd and shadow files for all email accounts. However, if I edit them manually I am still able to send email :-(

If I can locate the file which *exim* uses to authenticate users and mangle the passwords there, that would solve my issue...

Comment: Is there no way to invalidate passwords?

Comment: That's what I am asking @jcolebrand...

Comment: Are you asking about how to reset all user passwords yourself, prompting the customers to apply for a lost password, or are you asking about how to force the users to change their password upon next login?

Comment: Either one would do @Joe. I was thinking the former: change all email account passwords to some random string, and require the account owners to reset them within the master account admin. But as long as I can somehow force all users to make their passwords secure, I am happy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of cPanel 11.34.1.4 (CURRENT release at the time of writing), this is now a standard feature under **Account Functions »Force Password Change**.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the [Security Policies](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/SecurityPolicy#Password%20Age) to force a 'change date' of tomorrow? I'm thinking if you set a Password Age of 1 day, it will force them all to expire this time tomorrow. Once they're all expired, you can remove the limitation.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for *the cPanel account* and not for the email accounts within each cPanel account... :-(

Comment: I apologize, I didn't understand this was a tiered deployment. Hold please.

Comment: Done and done. :)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of trying this, but I was unsure if it would work. Also, doesn't it mean that everyone will have to reset their passwords on the same day? I may just have to use a 30 day limit...

Comment: Yes, everyone will have to do it on the same day. Isn't that what you were going for? Instantaneous?

Comment: What I was going for was to invalidate everyone's passwords *now*, but allow them to change them over the course of several days. My thinking is, if I set it to 1 day, then after that day I have to increase it otherwise the people who did change their passwords will have to change them again. Which means anyone who doesn't change their password escapes the new requirement...  I need to test this option I suppose and see how it actually works.